# Freeform: Specify alternate return url for spam submissions

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform, spam

I'm using a custom Return URL for my Freeform 3.13.7 forms to submit data to a CRM. The issue I'm running into is that my Spam Protection Behavior is set to "Simulate Success", which means all of the spam, which is properly filtered out in Freeform, is fed into my CRM.

Is there any way that I can specify an alternate Return URL for spam, or any other option than Display Errors?

Comment: Having the same issue with 3.x and trying to figure out a solve. The expected behavior, even with "Simulate Success" should be that the submission gets sent to the Freeform "Spam Folder" and not released to the CRM (or a custom webhook) until someone approves it. I'm wondering if this is a specific issue with the 3.x version of the plugin and or if this is also happening in version 4?

Answer (score 1):

Having an alternate Return URL for spam submissions would negate the whole point of the "Simulate Success" functionality. Instead, CRM integrations should be coded server-side in a module or plugin. That way it should only send the non-spam ones to the CRM.

You can hook into the following events in Freeform to send the data to your CRM:

https://docs.solspace.com/craft/freeform/v4/developer/submission-events.html

Freeform Pro also has some built-in CRM integrations for some of the more popular CRMs, but coding it yourself in a custom module is actually quite simple, and gives you full control (e.g. it gives you an extra opportunity to alter the submitted data if necessary).